# Sequence of Tenses in a relative clause

Tags: past-perfect

I was reading an article and something about tenses made me confused.

" Before then, I ***had never come*** across anyone who ***had stayed*** clean without using any drugs or alcohol. My only frame of reference ***had been*** junkies who ***fell*** into two categories: alive or dead."

My question is that why he is not using "**had fallen**" instead of "**fell**" like he did in the first sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here simple past(fall) is used because it describes a general situation prevalent at that time.
 If I say

> I have done the work which requires much hard work.

If I convert it into the past

> I had done the work which required much hard work.